# Grouping a data set by the key of an object and producing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a set of data which I have grouped by the key of the object - For each key of the object I need to produce an array of the id's . So instead of an array of object it is just a flat array of the id's.

I have managed to get the data back but can't seem to get just the id's out.

Here is the data set

```
let result =     {

  "age_group_ids": [
    {
      "id": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 9
    }
  ],
  "family_group_ids": [
    {
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 1
    }
  ],
  "earnings_group_ids": [
    {
      "id": 7
    },
    {
      "id": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the function I have written but it does not seem to work.

```
 Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
        return result[key].map(item =>  {
          item.id
        })
    })
```

The end result I want an object like this

```
{"age_group_ids": [5,4, 3, 9],
"family_group_ids": [2, 1],
"earnings_group_ids": [7,6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning from the `forEach`, assign the results back the `result[key]`. Removed the curly brackets arround the `item.id` of the map, so value would be added to the array.

```js
const result = {"age_group_ids":[{"id":5},{"id":4},{"id":3},{"id":9}],"family_group_ids":[{"id":2},{"id":1}],"earnings_group_ids":[{"id":7},{"id":6}]};

Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
  result[key] = result[key].map(item => item.id)
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let result = {"age_group_ids":[{"id":5},{"id":4},{"id":3},{"id":9}],"family_group_ids":[{"id":2},{"id":1}],"earnings_group_ids":[{"id":7},{"id":6}]};

function groupById(groups) {
  return Object.keys(groups).reduce((result, key) => {
    result[key] = result[key] || [];
    result[key] = groups[key].map(o => o.id);
    return result;
  }, {});
}

console.log(groupById(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for convenience so you don't have to use a scoped reference to `result[key]`. You can also use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to reference `key`, `values`, and `id` in a more concise way. Don't forget that you need to initialize `acc` to an empty object for the `reduce()` callback:

```js
const result = {age_group_ids:[{id:5},{id:4},{id:3},{id:9}],family_group_ids:[{id:2},{id:1}],earnings_group_ids:[{id:7},{id:6}]}


const output = Object.entries(result).reduce((acc, [key, values]) => Object.assign(acc, {
  [key]: values.map(({ id }) => id)
}), {})

console.log(output)
```